# List of ffmpeg container formats?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I read a full list of ffmpeg containers?
I know : `mp4, adts, h264, flv, mpegts`.
But how can I read full list of them?
The command line `ffmpeg -codecs`

```
Codecs:
D..... = Decoding supported
.E.... = Encoding supported
..V... = Video codec
..A... = Audio codec
..S... = Subtitle codec
...I.. = Intra frame-only codec
....L. = Lossy compression
.....S = Lossless compression
-------
```

has no data about it.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - codecs are different from container formats. For example an AVI (container) can any number of audio or video codecs

Comment: The muxers he referred to are the containers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Found this! :-)

```
ffmpeg -formats
```